# query executed the first time in pgAdmin returns results, if I try to re-execute it again, I get an empty set. Why is this?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

This is the query, which is a join between two tables where i filter only the rows with timestamps that are in the range of two seconds.

```
SELECT  t1.value as delta_pressure , temperature_readings,
        t1.time AS delta_pressure_time, t2.time AS temperature_time
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM real_delta_pressure
      LIMIT 40000) AS t1
JOIN (SELECT *
      FROM readings_temperature
      where device_id =20
      LIMIT 40000) AS t2
ON t1.device_id = t2.device_id
WHERE t1.time >= t2.time - interval '2 seconds'
AND t1.time <= t2.time + interval '2 seconds'
```

When i run the query the first time, I get results. If i re-execute it, I get an empty set. I have to reboot my computer and load pgAdmin again to make the query return results.

Comment: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` does not generate a stable resultset.

Comment: have you looked for an update of postgres

Comment: 1) Are you changing the parameters in the query e.g. `device_id = <some_number>`?  2) Try the query in `psql` multiple times.

Comment: @GMB, I am not seeing how that applies in this case. Lack of an `ORDER BY` means you can't count on the rows being ordered the same way between runs. It does not mean results will not be returned assuming the filtering clauses actually match values in the table(s).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: well if the results of the subqueries are not stable, the join might not find a match. Eg: what if the `select * from real_delta_pressure` now yields rows whose `device_id` is other than `20`?

Comment: Yeah but that won't be necessarily be fixed by an `order by`, it requires a `where device_id =20`.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but a suggestion:

```
SELECT  
   t1.value as delta_pressure , temperature_readings,
   t1.time AS delta_pressure_time, t2.time AS temperature_time
FROM 
    real_delta_pressure AS t1
JOIN 
    readings_temperature AS t2
ON 
    t1.device_id = t2.device_id
WHERE 
    t1.device_id = 20
AND 
    t1.time BETWEEN t2.time - interval '2 seconds' AND t2.time + interval '2 seconds'
ORDER BY
    t1.device_id
LIMIT 
    40000
```